# Variable not staying set coming from delegate

Tags: ios, swift

i have a delegate function "getHeight" that is sending me the height of a parent viewcontroller to another view.

I am receiving the height and setting it to a variable "receivedScreenHeight"

This is really weird, i must be doing something very silly, but the variable "receivedScreenHeight" is not staying set.

if i print it as soon as it is received it returns 667.00  but if i print it as the result of an action it returns nil.

this is my code section:

```
protocol GetMyScreenHeightDelegate {
    func getHeight(height: CGFloat)
}

class pageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, GetMyScreenHeightDelegate {


var receivedScreenHeight: CGFloat!


func getHeight(height: CGFloat) {

    print("the height got sent at... \(height)")

    self.receivedScreenHeight = height

    print("the height is set at... \(self.receivedScreenHeight)")

}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
    if (completed && finished) {
        if let currentVC = pageViewController.viewControllers?.last {
            let index = vcArr.index(of: currentVC)

            print("the height remains at... \(self.receivedScreenHeight)")

                //delegate2?.getIndex(index: index!)
            if index == 3 {


                //self.view.frame.size.height = receivedScreenHeight
                self.reloadInputViews()
                self.view.setNeedsLayout()

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the console:

```
the height got sent at... 667.0
the height is set at... Optional(667.0)
the height remains at... nil
```

i can see nowhere that this got changes, but it suddenly returns nil?

----- EDIT -----

section of code from LandingPageViewController that assigns the delegate and calls function

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // declare delegate
    self.delegate = pageViewController()

    // call delegate
    let height = self.view.frame.height
    delegate?.getHeight(height: height)
```

LandingPageController on left, pageViewController on right

[image]

Comment: One possibility is that the two methods are being executed on different instances of the same class.  Try printing self to see.

Comment: looks like you might be right.                                    <Swift.pageViewController: 0x7f9c1b849000>
<Swift.pageViewController: 0x7f9c1b84ae00>
<Swift.pageViewController: 0x7f9c1b84ae00>
<Swift.pageViewController: 0x7f9c1b84ae00>

Comment: Can you show the code where you set this VC as the delegate?  The problem probably lies there.

Comment: Yes - that creates a new instance of `pageViewController`, it doesn't get a reference to the existing one.  Next Question: how do you create the `LandingPageViewController` instance?

Comment: the LandingPageViewController is a viewcontroller that has a containerView in it.  this containerView has an embedded pageController which is of class pageViewController. ill stick a screenshot on the question

Comment: OK.  Try `self.delegate = self.childViewControllers[0] as! pageViewController` in place of `self.delegate = pageViewController()`.

Comment: Perfect thank you. i had never seen this before